# how to enumerate a specific column of a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to enumerate the second column of the input file but my code gives the below error. How can I fix my code to get the below output file?

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./rename_atoms.py", line 7,
>   in 
>       print(item+index) TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open ('input.gro', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        column=line.split()
        for index, item in enumerate(column[1]):
            print(item+index)
```

Input file:

```
GRoups of Organic Molecules in ACtion for Science
   18
    1LIG      O    1   1.665   1.740   8.646
    1LIG      O    2   0.877   2.044   7.947
    1LIG      S    3   1.469   1.778   8.501
    1LIG      S    4   1.340   1.695   8.487
    1LIG      S    5   1.231   1.770   8.412
    1LIG      N    6   1.282   1.801   8.268
    1LIG      C    7   1.553   1.679   8.585
    1LIG      C    8   1.523   1.805   8.360
    1LIG      C    9   1.313   1.647   8.630
    1LIG      H   10   1.418   1.875   8.271
    1LIG      H   11   1.454   1.624   8.688
    1LIG      H   12   1.100   1.691   8.403
    1LIG      H   13   1.453   1.912   8.577
    1LIG      H   14   1.174   1.869   8.184
    1LIG      H   15   0.992   1.777   8.339
    1LIG      H   16   1.037   1.853   8.217
    1LIG      H   17   1.206   1.941   8.068
    1LIG      H   18   0.939   1.914   8.137
      0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Desired output file:

```
GRoups of Organic Molecules in ACtion for Science
   18
    1LIG      O1    1   1.665   1.740   8.646
    1LIG      O2    2   0.877   2.044   7.947
    1LIG      S1    3   1.469   1.778   8.501
    1LIG      S2    4   1.340   1.695   8.487
    1LIG      S3    5   1.231   1.770   8.412
    1LIG      N1    6   1.282   1.801   8.268
    1LIG      C1    7   1.553   1.679   8.585
    1LIG      C2    8   1.523   1.805   8.360
    1LIG      C3    9   1.313   1.647   8.630
    1LIG      H1   10   1.418   1.875   8.271
    1LIG      H2   11   1.454   1.624   8.688
    1LIG      H3   12   1.100   1.691   8.403
    1LIG      H4   13   1.453   1.912   8.577
    1LIG      H5   14   1.174   1.869   8.184
    1LIG      H6   15   0.992   1.777   8.339
    1LIG      H7   16   1.037   1.853   8.217
    1LIG      H8   17   1.206   1.941   8.068
    1LIG      H9   18   0.939   1.914   8.137
      0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
  for index, item in enumerate(column[1]):
>>      print(item+index)
```

You are trying to add an int (`index`) and a string (`item`). If you just want them printed together, simply do:

```
print(item, index)
```

Note that this will add a space between the arguments by default. To remove that, use the `sep` argument, and set it to an empty string.

However, this probably is not what you want, as the output would be something like:

```
O 0
O 0
S 0
```

...and so on.

So, do this:

```
for i, l in enumerate(f):
    column = l.split()
    print(column[1],i,sep='')
```

This will be something like:

```
O0
O1
S2
```

...and so on.

Almost there. To get the desired output, we need to maintain counts of each of the elements. So, try something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
for l in f:
    column = l.split()
    counts[column[1]] += 1
    print(column[1], counts[column[1]], sep="")
```

This should print:

```
O1
O2
S1
```

...and so on.

Comment: Your code gives this error: `File "./rename_atoms.py", line 9
    print(column[1], counts[column[1]], sep='')
                                           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. It points out  `sep=''`

Comment: If that's the case please tag the question with `python2` as well, and use `print column[1] + str(counts[column[1]])` instead

Comment: It works now. But how can I get the desired output file (please see the desired output file at the end of question)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate an int and a string. They are incompatible types for the + function. You'll need to convert your index from int to string, then concatenate them. In line 7, try:

> ```
>         print(item+str(index))
> ```

Comment: I did it but the code prints out this `O0
O0
S0
S0
S0
N0
C0
C0
C0
H0
H0
H0
H0
H0
H0
H0
H0
H0` , which is not what I want.